# BringChildToFront() doesn't work upon moving back one fragment in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been trying to sample some code so that upon switching to a new fragment, a button is added to a linearLayout and upon leaving the fragment, the button is removed.

The issue that I can't seem to stop occurs only when swiping in one direction for any amount of fragments and then moving back one fragment. Rather than the button being removed at index 0, the button appears to stay at the last index while the textView at index 0 is removed.

Then, as long as that specific fragment is within one swipe of being active it will continue to remove views every time it is called upon until all the views are removed and an error occurs causing the app to crash.

Here is the code for my Fragment:

```
package com.timeblocks.timeblocks;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DaySliderFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.single_day_content, container, false);

        Button testBut = new Button(getContext());
        LinearLayout timeBars = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeBars);
        timeBars.addView(testBut);
        timeBars.bringChildToFront(testBut);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();

       LinearLayout timeBars = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timeBars);
       timeBars.removeViewAt(0);

    }
}
```

[Here is an animation of what is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNkaS.jpg)

Eventually, I intend to change the LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout and the button to a textView with data gathered from a database. Not certain this changes anything but figured I'd include it.

Comment: this `LinearLayout timeBars = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeBars);` referenced in `onCreateView` & this `LinearLayout timeBars = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timeBars);` referenced in `onDestroyView` are different `ViewGroup`s - surely you want to reference the same `ViewGroup`? Also check the `Fragment` callbacks being called as expected. Maybe post an animation of the problem.

Comment: I changed the top reference to `getActivity()` instead of `rootView` just to see if that changed anything and the app crashed completely. I'll try to find a way to record and post the error that is occuring.

Comment: no need -  `onActivityCreated` has not yet been called in the `Fragment` meaning calling `getActivity` in `onCreateView` will cause a `NullPointerException`

Comment: so how can I prevent this issue? Should I be changing the layout in a different method?